# Validating entities before saving and removing from context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to validate entities that I've already added to the context before I call `SaveChanges` and remove the invalid ones so that I don't get the `EntityValidationErrors` on save?

I have a list of about 3k entities and some of them contain invalid data that prevent all other entities to be saved. I wouldn't like to save each entity separately but rather ignore those that have errors.

Trying to find a solution to this I found that you can disable the validation. If I did it, would `SaveChanges` ignore the invalid ones and save the others?

```
Context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

I would however prefer to call some method to invoke entity validation and remove it from the context. Or maybe it's even possible to validate an entity before I add it to the context? This would be even better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The direct solution is validating them before save, and detach those entities with errors.

```
foreach (var error in dbContext.GetValidationErrors())
{
    dbContext.Entry(error.Entry).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

But it's more like a workaround. IMO you should avoid the validation errors more earlier (e.g. in the api layer), instead of preventing from saving in the data layer.

Comment: Yes, I mean it like a workaround. I'm going to log the invalid data and look for the bug later but it'd be great if at least some of the data could be saved otherwise one invalid entity paralyses the whole system. It's not always easy to prevent and predict every kind of possible errors. This should be the last resort error detection and prevention.

Answer (score 2):

Find Model Properties using **ViewData.ModelState.Errors;**

```
  foreach (var item in ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
            {
                int err=ViewData.ModelState[item].Errors.Count();
                if (err.Equals(1))
                {
                  // Add property name in a list 
                }
            }
```

After this Exclude those Properties using

```
 db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
 db.Entry(model).Property(x => x.Token).IsModified = false;
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. In this very situation it won't help me but it's good to know that I can disable particular properties. I'll save it for future reference ;-)