# Discard invalid entities before save in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I used the accepted solution at this link for
a similar problem to the OP. [Validating entities before saving and removing from context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404334/validating-entities-before-saving-and-removing-from-context)

In Entity Framewok 6 I get System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type DbEntityEntry is not part of the model for the current context.'

How do I work around that? Is there something I have to include in my initial setup?

My code looks like this

```cs
            Console.WriteLine("Removing Bad Records");
            foreach (var error in context.GetValidationErrors())
            {
                context.Entry(error.Entry).State = EntityState.Detached;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Saving Changes");
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is why you need to be _very careful_ around any method that accepts an untyped `Object` as a parameter argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `context.Entry( Object )` returns an `DbEntityEntry<>` object for the specified *entity* object.
- `error.Entry` **is already** an `DbEntityEntry<>` object. It is not an *entity* object.

So change your code to this (setting `State` on your `error.Entry`):

```
Console.WriteLine("Removing Bad Records");
foreach( var error in context.GetValidationErrors() )
{
    error.Entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
}

Console.WriteLine("Saving Changes");
context.SaveChanges();
```

...or this (passing the actual *entity* object into `dbContext.Entry(Object)`):

```
Console.WriteLine("Removing Bad Records");
foreach( var error in context.GetValidationErrors() )
{
    var entity = error.Entry.Entity;
    context.Entry( entity ).State = EntityState.Detached;
}

Console.WriteLine("Saving Changes");
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: If it helps anyone in the future, I went with the first suggestion and it worked exactly as I wanted.